# How to use val instead of var in below Scala Code

Tags: scala, variables, var

How to use val instead of var in below Scala Code

```
var index: Long = lower
     var sum = 0L
      while(index <= upper) {
       if(number % index == 0L)
        sum += index
        index += 1L
     }
     sum
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(lower to upper).filter(number % _ == 0).sum
```